# Improving performance of Android ListView which currently uses database count aggregation

Tags: java, android, database, performance, android-listview

Right now, I have an app with a ListView. In each row, there is a TextView that shows the number of times that item has been favorited, which is represented in a Favorites table.

Currently, that number is gotten by using a count(*) aggregation on the number of times that itemID appears in the table. So every time a user favorites an item, it should add a row to the table and increment the number. However, as this calculation and redrawing has to happen for every row in the ListView, it takes about 2 seconds for the changes to occur.

Are there any improvements I can make to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a "favorited_count" column to the "item" table that gets incremented whenever the item is favorited.  Although this may end up duplicating information e. g. rows in the "favorited" table, it should perform a *whole lot better* than running count(*) on the "favorited" table, especially as it continues to grow in size.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code its hard to tell, however there are a few things you might check.

Are you using View Holder pattern (suggested by google) this avoids unwanted parsing through the list item's layout every time it is drawn.

See this,

- http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Make sure your list-item layout is optimized,

- http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html